# Computing points for a football team

Tags: r, loops

everyone.
I am trying to calculate football team points.
I have my dataframe "df.work" with rownames = teamnames:
`rownames(df.work) <- c(as.vector(teams$HomeTeam))`

I have imported all played matches from another dataframe.
And for every team I try to execute if loop based on subset of team matches. First I filter all home matches.
So my code is

```
for (Team1 in row.names.data.frame(df.work)){
a1 <- filter(df.clean, HomeTeam == Team1)
  if (a1$home.goals > a1$away.goals) {
    df.work[Team1,"Points"] <- df.work[Team1,"Points"] + 3
  } else  if(a1$home.goals == a1$away.goals) {
    df.work[Team1,"Points"] <- df.work[Team1,"Points"] + 1
  }
```

But I struggle why it did not loop for every row in a1 and sum the points?

Edit:
this is head(df.clean):

```
        HomeTeam         AwayTeam home.goals away.goals
1      Liverpool          Norwich          4          1
2       West Ham         Man City          0          5
3    Bournemouth Sheffield United          1          1
4        Burnley      Southampton          3          0
5 Crystal Palace          Everton          0          0
6        Watford         Brighton          0          3
```

and head(df.work) is

```
               Games Goals.Scored Goals.Conceded Points 
Liverpool         32           70             25      3 
West Ham          32           38             56      0
Bournemouth       32           30             54      1
Burnley           32           36             45      3
Crystal Palace    32           28             37      1
Watford           32           29             49      0
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(df.clean, 20))` in the question, please?

Comment: Sorry, the question is edited to include the head data.

Comment: (1) Well, in the code snippet you posted, there's no closing bracket for the `for` loop.  Is that just a typo?  (2)  Also, a good rule of thumb for working in R is "if you're using a loop, there's almost certainly a better way to do it".  I strongly suspect that  is the case here.  (3)  Personally, I dislike row names, as they automatically make the data untidy.  (4) Without your full data and code, it's difficult to be certain what the problem is.  Your source data is all English Premier League results for 2019-2020, correct?

Comment: (1) there is closing bracket. (2) Your comment proved successful after many hours of looking that loop, I've decided to create a vector with difference between scored and conceded goals and just count the positive values and the zeroes. Lol, so simple... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dplyr solution to transform `df.clean` into the desired result without using loops. The data set was easy enough to replicate from public resources.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df.clean %>% 
  pivot_longer(1:2, names_to = "HA", values_to = "Team") %>% 
  group_by(Team) %>%
  mutate(Goals.Conceded = ifelse(HA == "HomeTeam", away.goals, home.goals)) %>%
  mutate(Goals.Scored = ifelse(HA == "HomeTeam", home.goals, away.goals)) %>%
  mutate(Points = ifelse(Goals.Scored > Goals.Conceded, 3,
                         ifelse(Goals.Scored == Goals.Conceded, 1, 0))) %>%
  mutate(Games = 1) %>% 
  select(c(8, 6:5, 7)) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  arrange(-Points)
```

Which yields:

```
#> # A tibble: 20 x 5
#>    Team           Games Goals.Scored Goals.Conceded Points
#>    <fct>          <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 Liverpool         32           70             25     86
#>  2 Man City          32           81             33     66
#>  3 Leicester         32           60             31     55
#>  4 Chelsea           32           57             44     54
#>  5 Man Utd           32           51             31     52
#>  6 Wolves            32           45             34     52
#>  7 Sheffield Utd     32           33             32     47
#>  8 Arsenal           32           47             41     46
#>  9 Burnley           32           36             45     45
#> 10 Spurs             32           51             44     45
#> 11 Everton           32           40             47     44
#> 12 Crystal Palace    32           28             37     42
#> 13 Newcastle         32           33             43     42
#> 14 Southampton       32           41             55     40
#> 15 Brighton          32           34             44     33
#> 16 West Ham          32           38             56     30
#> 17 Watford           32           29             49     28
#> 18 Aston Villa       32           36             60     27
#> 19 Bournemouth       32           30             54     27
#> 20 Norwich           32           25             60     21
```

---

**Data**

```r
df.clean <- structure(list(HomeTeam = structure(c(10L, 19L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 18L, 
17L, 9L, 13L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 14L, 16L, 11L, 15L, 6L, 20L, 
2L, 14L, 4L, 12L, 15L, 18L, 10L, 3L, 17L, 20L, 16L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 
11L, 13L, 19L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 12L, 15L, 17L, 20L, 14L, 
3L, 18L, 2L, 16L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 7L, 19L, 1L, 6L, 15L, 
3L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 17L, 20L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 14L, 18L, 
19L, 1L, 11L, 16L, 13L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 17L, 20L, 7L, 12L, 
15L, 16L, 11L, 4L, 18L, 19L, 5L, 13L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 11L, 15L, 19L, 18L, 7L, 8L, 14L, 6L, 5L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 9L, 
12L, 20L, 10L, 19L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 18L, 11L, 15L, 2L, 13L, 
5L, 6L, 10L, 17L, 16L, 14L, 20L, 9L, 12L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 20L, 12L, 
6L, 16L, 10L, 15L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 17L, 18L, 11L, 2L, 13L, 14L, 4L, 
19L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 15L, 16L, 12L, 20L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 13L, 14L, 11L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 15L, 12L, 
9L, 20L, 4L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 14L, 19L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 
13L, 16L, 18L, 11L, 14L, 19L, 1L, 10L, 15L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 
20L, 17L, 3L, 2L, 18L, 1L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 16L, 19L, 13L, 5L, 10L, 
3L, 2L, 8L, 15L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 17L, 12L, 20L, 19L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 
10L, 13L, 18L, 19L, 12L, 5L, 17L, 8L, 4L, 15L, 20L, 16L, 14L, 
2L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 15L, 16L, 9L, 12L, 20L, 1L, 10L, 
14L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 19L, 18L, 8L, 17L, 10L, 1L, 7L, 15L, 16L, 20L, 
5L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 4L, 19L, 3L, 13L, 2L, 
8L, 11L, 9L, 17L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 20L, 10L, 5L, 16L, 6L, 2L, 18L, 
7L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 19L, 15L, 11L), .Label = c("Arsenal", "Aston Villa", 
"Bournemouth", "Brighton", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", 
"Everton", "Leicester", "Liverpool", "Man City", "Man Utd", "Newcastle", 
"Norwich", "Sheffield Utd", "Southampton", "Spurs", "Watford", 
"West Ham", "Wolves"), class = "factor"), AwayTeam = structure(c(14L, 
11L, 15L, 16L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 20L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 19L, 18L, 13L, 
10L, 17L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 8L, 6L, 16L, 7L, 9L, 19L, 1L, 11L, 13L, 
5L, 12L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 18L, 14L, 10L, 20L, 17L, 13L, 5L, 9L, 
16L, 7L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 1L, 19L, 3L, 17L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 20L, 
12L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 19L, 5L, 4L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 11L, 13L, 1L, 
17L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 15L, 7L, 3L, 20L, 6L, 12L, 19L, 14L, 4L, 13L, 
5L, 18L, 16L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 15L, 6L, 20L, 7L, 
17L, 12L, 12L, 20L, 10L, 14L, 16L, 5L, 13L, 6L, 9L, 17L, 18L, 
7L, 19L, 3L, 8L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 11L, 17L, 20L, 16L, 9L, 10L, 
14L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 7L, 19L, 4L, 3L, 18L, 1L, 15L, 8L, 
2L, 3L, 11L, 18L, 19L, 17L, 2L, 14L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 
7L, 12L, 9L, 16L, 15L, 20L, 1L, 18L, 13L, 3L, 14L, 2L, 19L, 8L, 
17L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 16L, 15L, 7L, 20L, 9L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 
14L, 16L, 19L, 5L, 18L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 17L, 9L, 
12L, 6L, 20L, 15L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 17L, 20L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 12L, 15L, 
19L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 16L, 14L, 13L, 10L, 18L, 11L, 17L, 15L, 2L, 
7L, 3L, 20L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 4L, 18L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 1L, 19L, 
14L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 15L, 16L, 14L, 8L, 4L, 20L, 1L, 11L, 
7L, 18L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 17L, 13L, 12L, 19L, 17L, 3L, 13L, 4L, 
2L, 11L, 18L, 14L, 8L, 19L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 16L, 10L, 12L, 20L, 
3L, 19L, 18L, 14L, 13L, 4L, 17L, 8L, 11L, 2L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 12L, 
9L, 1L, 20L, 7L, 15L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 19L, 15L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 
7L, 18L, 1L, 11L, 20L, 16L, 5L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 9L, 6L, 17L, 10L
), .Label = c("Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Bournemouth", "Brighton", 
"Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Leicester", 
"Liverpool", "Man City", "Man Utd", "Newcastle", "Norwich", "Sheffield Utd", 
"Southampton", "Spurs", "Watford", "West Ham", "Wolves"), class = "factor"), 
    home.goals = c(4, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
    3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
    2, 0, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 
    1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
    3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    5, 0, 1, 3, 0, 5, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 
    1, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 
    2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 
    1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 
    0, 4, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 2, 
    3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 2, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 
    5, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 2, 3, 
    3, 4), away.goals = c(1, 5, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 
    1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 5, 2, 1, 2, 0, 
    3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    1, 0, 9, 0, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 
    2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 6, 0, 1, 
    1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 
    2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 0, 
    1, 2, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 320L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This good example of why I believe tidy data is so important.  The solution to the question is not difficult, but it is made harder by having the data in a less-than-optimal form.  This solution converts the data to tidy form and answers the OP's original question all in less code than it took to solve the question using the data in the Op's original form.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following is what the question asks for.

```
goals2points <- function(x, y){
  pnts <- sign(x - y) + 1
  pnts[pnts == 2] <- 3
  sum(pnts)
}

hg <- aggregate(home.goals ~ HomeTeam, df.clean, sum)
ag <- aggregate(away.goals ~ AwayTeam, df.clean, sum)
Goals.Scored <- hg[[2]] + ag[[2]]
hg <- aggregate(home.goals ~ AwayTeam, df.clean, sum)
ag <- aggregate(away.goals ~ HomeTeam, df.clean, sum)
Goals.Conceded <- hg[[2]] + ag[[2]]

sp1 <- split(df.clean, df.clean$HomeTeam)
home <- sapply(sp1, function(DF){
  goals2points(DF[['home.goals']], DF[['away.goals']])
})

sp2 <- split(df.clean, df.clean$AwayTeam)
away <- sapply(sp2, function(DF){
  goals2points(DF[['away.goals']], DF[['home.goals']])
})

Points <- rowSums(cbind(home, away))
result <- data.frame(Games = lengths(sp1) + lengths(sp2), 
                     Goals.Scored, 
                     Goals.Conceded, 
                     Points)
result
#  Games Goals.Scored Goals.Conceded Points
#A     8           24             22     12
#B     8           26             21     15
#C     8           23             21     12
#D     8           17             24      7
#E     8           23             25     13
```

**Test data**

```
set.seed(2020)
df.clean <- expand.grid(HomeTeam = LETTERS[1:5], AwayTeam = LETTERS[1:5])
df.clean <- df.clean[apply(df.clean, 1, function(x) x[1] != x[2]), ]
df.clean$home.goals <- sample(0:5, nrow(df.clean), TRUE)
df.clean$away.goals <- sample(0:5, nrow(df.clean), TRUE)
```

Comment: You guys are awesome, thank you! I still have so much more to learn. Thank you for your valuable thoughts!