# Multithread computation with R: how to get all different random numbers?

Tags: r, random, foreach, doparallel

Anyone knows how to get all the random numbers different in the following code? E.g. with `doRNG` package? **I don't care about reproducibility.**

**Edit:** Duplicates by pure chance are accepted.

```
rm(list = ls())
set.seed(666)
cat("\014")
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(doRNG)

# ====== Data Preparation ======
dt = data.frame(id = 1:10,
                part = rep("dt",10),
                HG = c(1,3,6,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                random = NA)

# ====== Set Parallel Computing ======
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cl = makeCluster(3, outfile = "")
registerDoParallel(cl)

# ====== SIMULATION ======
nsim = 1000                # number of simulations
iterChunk = 100            # split nsim into this many chunks
out = data.frame()    # prepare output DF
for(iter in 1:ceiling(nsim/iterChunk)){
  strt = Sys.time()
  
  out_iter = 
    foreach(i = 1:iterChunk, .combine = rbind, .multicombine = TRUE, .maxcombine = 100000, .inorder = FALSE, .verbose = FALSE,
            .packages = c("plyr", "dplyr")) %dopar% {
              
              # simulation number
              id_sim = iterChunk * (iter - 1) + i

              ## Generate random numbers
              tmp_sim = is.na(dt$HG) # no results yet
              dt$random[tmp_sim] = runif(sum(tmp_sim))
              dt$HG[tmp_sim] = 3

              # Save Results
              dt$id_sim = id_sim
              dt$iter = iter
              dt$i = i
              
              print(Sys.time())
              return(dt)
            }#i;sim_forcycle
  
  out = rbind.data.frame(out,subset(out_iter, !is.na(random)))
  
  fnsh = Sys.time()
  cat(" [",iter,"] ",fnsh - strt, sep = "")
}#iter

# ====== Stop Parallel Computing ======
stopCluster(cl)

# ====== Distinct Random Numbers ======
length(unique(out$random))              # expectation: 6000
```

I have been strugling with this for 2 days. I [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755432/can-piece-of-r-code-influence-random-numbers-in-foreach-output) earlier with only general response about random numbers.

Here I would like to ask for a solution (if anybody knows) how to set `doRNG` package options (or similar package) in a way that **all the random numbers are different. Across all the loops.**

I have tried tons of doRNG settings and I still can't get it to work. Tried R versions 3.5.3 and 3.6.3 on two different computers.

---

**UPDATE** Following discussion with @Limey

Purpose of the code is to simulate football matches. As the simulation is large, I use `iterChunk` to "split" the simulation into managable parts and after each `iter` send the data into PostgreSQL database so the simulation doesn't overload RAM. Some matches already have real world results and have `HG` (home goals) filled in. I want to simulate the rest.

When setting `iterChunk` to `1` everything is fine. Increasing `iterChunk` leads to generation of same numbers within `iter`. For example when I set `nsim` to `100` and `iterChunk` to `10`. (All matches simulated 100 times, 10 times in 10 loops). I expect 600 random numbers (each match independently simulated accross all the loops). However I only get 180 - following the logic: 3 cores * 6 matches * 10 iterChunks.) Using 2 workers I do get 120 distinct random numbers (2 * 6 * 10)

Furthermore: exluding `dt$HG[tmp_sim] = 3` I do get all random numbers different with whatever setting.

To understand the problem, I suggest:

1. Run the code as is. (possibly setting `nsim` to `100` and `iterChunk` to `10`)  You will get 180 different random numbers. With lower number of nsim & iterChunk things may work as expected.
2. Comment out `dt$HG[tmp_sim] = 3`.
   You will get 6000 different random numbers (600 if you change `nsim` and `iterChunk`)

The code in 2nd step assigns goals scored by home team. It looks like some kind of bug I can't get over. Even information that someone gets the same result and doesn't know why will be helpful - it will lift the weight of my own stupidity out of me.

Thank you, I highly appreciate any effort.

Comment: If you don't need reproducibility, is your use of `set.seed` only for this question? Does your code work as desired *without* `set.seed`?

Comment: It's my default header I use in the beginning of all my codes... sorry for confusion.

Comment: Do you mean "all different", to say "random numbers that are _almost surely_ different", that is, they can only be different by accident?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised what the problem with OP's code was whilst I was in the shower.  It's simple, and obvious in retrospect: all the loops and parallel processes are working on the same object - the `dt` data frame.  So they're constantly overwriting the changes that each makes, and at the end of the outer loop, you just have multiple copies of the changes made by the last loop to complete.  The solution is equally simple: work on a copy of the `dt` data frame.

To minimise the changes, I renamed `dt` to `baseDT`

```
# ====== Data Preparation ======
baseDT = data.frame(id = 1:10,
                part = rep("dt",10),
                HG = c(1,3,6,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                random = NA)
```

and then took a copy of it at the top of the `foreach` loop

```
  out_iter = foreach(i = 1:iterChunk, 
               .combine = rbind, .multicombine = TRUE, .maxcombine = 100000, 
               .inorder = FALSE, .verbose = FALSE,
               .packages = c("plyr", "dplyr")) %dopar% {
    dt <- baseDT
```

This gives

```
> length(unique(out$random))              # expectation: 6000
[1] 6000
```

as expected.

Comment: Believe me or not, I had this explanation on my mind. I didn't try to solve it like you did because of the `dt$HG[tmp_sim] = 3` thing. With this piece of code it overwrites and without it it does not.

My simulation is more complex, it works with more data frames in a similar way, concatenating them into a list which is then spit out by the `foreach`. Problem presented here applies to some of the DFs and not to the others. I would expect all of them to be overwriten due to the parallel computation... BUT your solution works here. **Thank you one more time!**

Comment: Here, the underlying cause is that an object is shared between parallel processes without any synchronization; see also my answer to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755432/can-piece-of-r-code-influence-random-numbers-in-foreach-output).  Here, the solution to problems like this is either to synchronize access to those objects, or to give each process a copy of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the "Hello World" example in the "getting started with doParallel" [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf) to generate random numbers, I came up with:

```
library(doParallel)

cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
myFunc <- function(n) {runif(n)}
foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% myFunc(10)
[[1]]
 [1] 0.18492375 0.13388278 0.65455450 0.93093066 0.41157625 0.89479764 0.14736529 0.47935995 0.03062963 0.16110714

[[2]]
 [1] 0.89245145 0.20980791 0.83828019 0.04411547 0.38184303 0.48110619 0.51509058 0.93732055 0.40159834 0.81414140

[[3]]
 [1] 0.74393129 0.66999730 0.44411989 0.85040773 0.80224527 0.72483644 0.64566262 0.22546420 0.14526819 0.05931329
```

Suggesting that getting random numbers across threads is straightforward.  Indeed, the examples on pages 2 and 3 of the doRNG [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRNG/vignettes/doRNG.pdf) say the same thing.

In fact, if I understand you correctly, the purpose of `doRNG` is to do precisely the opposite of what you want: to make random processes reproducible across threads.

Of course, this doesn't guarantee that all numbers are different across all threads.  But it makes duplication very unlikely.  A guarantee of no duplicates would mean some degree of determinism in the process: a completely random process *might* produce duplicates by chance.

**Update**
Following on from our conversation in the comments...

We've established that the problem is in your program logic, not the parallelisation *per se*.  So we need to refocus the question: what are you *trying* to do.  I'm afraid it's not at all clear to me.  So *that* means we need to simplify.

I set `nsim` to `5` and `iterChunk` to `1`.  I get 5 data frames which look like

```
   id part HG    random id_sim iter i
1   1   dt  1        NA      1    1 1
2   2   dt  3        NA      1    1 1
3   3   dt  6        NA      1    1 1
4   4   dt  3 0.6919744      1    1 1
5   5   dt  3 0.5413398      1    1 1
6   6   dt  2        NA      1    1 1
7   7   dt  3 0.3983175      1    1 1
8   8   dt  3 0.3342174      1    1 1
9   9   dt  3 0.6126020      1    1 1
10 10   dt  3 0.4185468      1    1 1
```

In each, the values of `id_sim` and `iter` are always the same, and run from `1` in the first data frame to `5` in the fifth.  `i` is `1` for all rows in all data frames.  Values in `random` do appear to be random, and different between data frames.  But the `NA`s are all in the same positions in every data frame: the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 6th rows.  The values of `HG` are as shown above for all five data frames.

Is that what you would expect?  If not, what do you expect?  Given we know the problem is not the paraellisation, you need to give us more information.

**Update 2**

Do you know [Arduan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62740230/computing-points-for-a-football-team/62741219#62741219)?  They posted a related question over the weekend...

I'm not going to tell you what's wrong with your code.  I'll show you how I would apprach your problem.  I hope you'll agree it's more readable, if nothing else.

So, we're simulating some football matches.  I'll assume its a league format and use the english Premier League as an example.  Start by generating the fixture list for a single season.

```
library(tidyverse)

teams <- c("Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Bournemouth", "Brighton & Hove Albion", 
           "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Leicester City", 
           "Liverpool", "Manchester City", "Manchester United", "Newcastle United", 
           "Norwich City", "Sheffield United", "Southampton", "Tottenham Hotspur", 
           "Watford", "West Ham United", "Wolverhampton Wanderers")

fixtures <- tibble(HomeTeam=teams, AwayTeam=teams) %>% 
              complete(HomeTeam, AwayTeam) %>% 
              filter(HomeTeam != AwayTeam) # A team can't play itself
fixtures %>% head(5)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  HomeTeam AwayTeam              
  <chr>    <chr>                 
1 Arsenal  Aston Villa           
2 Arsenal  Bournemouth           
3 Arsenal  Brighton & Hove Albion
4 Arsenal  Burnley               
5 Arsenal  Chelsea
```

Suppose we know some results.  I'll use yesterday's matches as an illustration.

```
knownResults <- tribble(~HomeTeam,          ~AwayTeam,         ~HomeGoals, ~AwayGoals,
                        "Burnley",          "Sheffield United",         1,          1,
                        "Newcastle United", "West Ham United",          2,          2,
                        "Liverpool",        "Aston Villa",              2,          0,
                        "Southampton",      "Manchester City",          1,          0)

resultsSoFar <- fixtures %>% 
             left_join(knownResults, by=c("HomeTeam", "AwayTeam"))
resultsSoFar %>% filter(!is.na(HomeGoals))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  HomeTeam         AwayTeam         HomeGoals AwayGoals
  <chr>            <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Burnley          Sheffield United         1         1
2 Liverpool        Aston Villa              2         0
3 Newcastle United West Ham United          2         2
4 Southampton      Manchester City          1         0
```

Now some utility functions.  You could certainly combine them, but I think it's clearer to keep them separate so you can see exactly what each one is doing.

First, a function to simulate the results of all matches whose results are unknown.  The details of how you simulate the scores are entirely arbitrary.  I've assumed that home teams score an average of 1.5 goals a game, away teams score 1.2 goals per game.  Later on, I'm going to use this to simulate many seasons in one go, so I'll add a variable (`Iteration`) to index the season.

```
simulateResults <- function(i=NA, data) {
  n <- nrow(data)
  data %>%
    add_column(Iteration=i, .before=1) %>% 
    mutate(
      # Give the home team a slight advantage
      HomeGoals=ifelse(is.na(HomeGoals), floor(rexp(n, rate=1/1.5)), HomeGoals),
      AwayGoals=ifelse(is.na(AwayGoals), floor(rexp(n, rate=1/1.2)), AwayGoals)
    )
}
```

Use it, and check that we haven't overwritten known results:

```
simulateResults(1, resultsSoFar) %>% filter(HomeTeam=="Burnley", AwayTeam=="Sheffield United")
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Iteration HomeTeam AwayTeam         HomeGoals AwayGoals
      <dbl> <chr>    <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>
1         1 Burnley  Sheffield United         1         1
```

I'm going to parallelise the overall simulation, so now let's have a function to simulate a chunk of simulations.  Again, create an index column to identify the chunk.

```
simulateChunk <- function(chunkID=NA, n) {
  bind_rows(lapply(1:n, simulateResults, data=resultsSoFar)) %>% 
    add_column(Chunk=chunkID, .before=1)
}
simulateChunk(chunkID=1, n=3)
# A tibble: 1,140 x 6
   Chunk Iteration HomeTeam AwayTeam               HomeGoals AwayGoals
   <dbl>     <int> <chr>    <chr>                      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1         1 Arsenal  Aston Villa                    2         0
 2     1         1 Arsenal  Bournemouth                    0         0
 3     1         1 Arsenal  Brighton & Hove Albion         2         0
 4     1         1 Arsenal  Burnley                        2         0
 5     1         1 Arsenal  Chelsea                        1         0
 6     1         1 Arsenal  Crystal Palace                 0         0
 7     1         1 Arsenal  Everton                        2         3
 8     1         1 Arsenal  Leicester City                 2         0
 9     1         1 Arsenal  Liverpool                      0         1
10     1         1 Arsenal  Manchester City                4         0
```

OK.  Now I'm ready to do the main simulation work.  I'll run 10 chunks of 100 simulations eash, to give 1000 simulated seasons in total, the same as you had.

```
library(doParallel)

cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)

chunkSize <- 100
nChunks <- 10

startedAt <- Sys.time()
x <- bind_rows(foreach(i=1:nChunks, .packages=c("tidyverse")) %dopar% simulateChunk(i, n=chunkSize))
finishedAt <- Sys.time()
print(finishedAt - startedAt)
Time difference of 6.772928 secs
stopCluster(cl)
> x
# A tibble: 380,000 x 6
   Chunk Iteration HomeTeam AwayTeam               HomeGoals AwayGoals
   <int>     <int> <chr>    <chr>                      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1         1 Arsenal  Aston Villa                    2         0
 2     1         1 Arsenal  Bournemouth                    3         1
 3     1         1 Arsenal  Brighton & Hove Albion         0         1
 4     1         1 Arsenal  Burnley                        3         0
 5     1         1 Arsenal  Chelsea                        1         0
 6     1         1 Arsenal  Crystal Palace                 0         0
 7     1         1 Arsenal  Everton                        1         2
 8     1         1 Arsenal  Leicester City                 0         0
 9     1         1 Arsenal  Liverpool                      0         0
10     1         1 Arsenal  Manchester City                0         0
```

Let's check I've got sensible results.  As a basic check, I'll look at the results of Arsenal vs Aston Villa:

```
x %>% 
  filter(HomeTeam == "Arsenal", AwayTeam=="Aston Villa") %>% 
  group_by(HomeGoals, AwayGoals) %>% 
  summarise(N=n(), .groups="drop") %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    values_from="N", names_prefix="AwayGoals", 
    names_sep="", names_from=AwayGoals
  )
# A tibble: 8 x 10
  HomeGoals AwayGoals0 AwayGoals1 AwayGoals2 AwayGoals3 AwayGoals4 AwayGoals5 AwayGoals6 AwayGoals8 AwayGoals7
      <dbl>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
1         0        299        129         57         19         12          7         NA         NA         NA
2         1        135         63         25          6          4          4          1          2         NA
3         2         75         21         12          9          4          1         NA         NA          1
4         3         30         13         10          1         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
5         4         21          7          1          1         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
6         5         11          2          1         NA          2         NA         NA         NA         NA
7         6          4          2          2         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
8         7          4          1          1         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

That looks reasonable.  Now confirm that the matches with known results don't vary.  For example:

```
x %>% 
  filter(HomeTeam == "Liverpool", AwayTeam=="Aston Villa") %>% 
  group_by(HomeGoals, AwayGoals) %>% 
  summarise(N=n(), .groups="drop") %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from="N", names_prefix="AwayGoals", names_sep="", names_from=AwayGoals)
  HomeGoals AwayGoals0
      <dbl>      <int>
1         2       1000
```

All good.

So, That's 23 statements to generate the fixtures, take account of known results, simulate the remainder of the matches and do some basic sanity checking.  I could easily get that down to under 20 statements if I had to.  That's about a third less than you were using just to try to simulate the unknown results.  [The actual simulation takes fewer than 10 statements.] I think my approach is easier to understand: by using [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) verbs the code is almost self-documenting.

Comment: Thanks :) If you take a look at my code, you will see that **I use doParallel exactly the way you (and the vignette) are suggesting**.

When you copy - paste my code, do you get all different? ... I am statisticians, so I do understand _"all different"_ is a simplification ;)

Comment: Please don't shout.  I hope we are all here to help each other.  As it happens, I did take a look at your code.  It seemed a good place to start to try to understand your problem. :) Let me ask you a question: if you run *my* code, do you get different random numbers from each thread?  If you do, then I would say the most probable source of the problem is with your code and not the parallelisation software you are trying to use.  @r2evans' siggestion also seems worthy of exploration.

Comment: I didn't mean the bold letters as shouting. I am really gratefull for your response. On the other hand I have to admit that this problem is driving me crazy... so I do apologize if it sounded badly ;)

I do get all different with your code and the seed doesn't matter. The crazy part is this: running my code as posted I get 180 distinct random numbers. When commenting out `dt$HG[tmp_sim] = 3` I do get all different. Could you please try? It's weird.

Comment: I added a description of the problem. Thank you once more :)

Comment: Thank you. I will go through your code and possible implement that. I appreciate the time and effort you put into this.

Let me just point out that you didn't respond to the random numbers problem. I surely could also come up with different approach.

The point is that it is difficult to move on when I don't know why adding home goals into dataframe destroyes random numbers in `foreach`. Have you tried what I described? Did it suprise you?

You surely are a better programmer than me. The goal was, however, to understand what is going on with random numbers, not to build new solution.